# show products on cms page under specified product id using "catalog/product/list.phtml" template

Tags: magento

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

with this code I can list all product from category having id 12. similarly is there any way I can display selected products using product id like this

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" product_id="15,88,17" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//You are on the right track. 
From your, which you have added in cms page,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" product_id="15,88,17" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

block,in your template file `catalog/product/list.phtml` call as below.

```
<?php
    $data=$this->getData('product_id');
    $product_ids = explode(',',$data);
?>
```

There are also other ways check  [here](http://magentophp.blogspot.in/2011/08/passing-paramters-to-magento-cms-static.html)

Comment: In which template file and where ?

Comment: catalog/product/list.phtml file

Comment: What is not working? Do you get $product_ids as values?

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting to where should I put this code in list.phtml and should I use `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` line to show selected product in cms page.

Comment: You can put the above code (in answer) wherever you would like to have your products displayed? You have assigned catalog/product/list.phtml template so you can put the above code in this file. You can have any template file to assign this block

Comment: Thanks Dushyant, with little modification it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So we can show a single product in the CMS Page content:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" name="home.catalog.product.view" alias="products_cms" product_id="product_id" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"}}
```

to display a list of desired products you need to change the load collection in the block.

Comment: I want in list.phtml template and give line of code displaying product page kind of layout.